# How do RC airplanes create thrust without using propellers or rockets?

Tags: model-aircraft

I haven't wondered how RC planes create thrust until now. I know some literally use rockets, but what about the small ones, that don't use propellers? How in the world do they manage to create thrust in the air without propellers, or rockets?

[image]

Also, how do they control aileron? Does an RC plane have a rudder? Do RCs have to be registered with local aviation authorities (if in Canada)?

Comment: Google electric ducted fan.  Many RC model planes fly just fine with no rudder-- especially if wingspan is not too large and flight speed is not too slow.  Laws regulating RC models vary from country to country and are getting ever more draconian-- in the US RC model flying as we know it will essentially be illegal if new regulations proposed by FAA this year actually end up going into effect.  Google "Remote ID NPRM".

Comment: Your last section should be asked separately. But the first couple may be considered off topic, and the last [has answers, depending on jurisdiction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24153/1696).

Comment: @fooot: There's a difference between an RC and a drone.

Comment: RC hobbyist quadcopters and rc airplane are all "small Unmanned Aerial Vehicles" in the eyes of the FAA here in the USA whether they are flown the normal way or by a camera onboard or autonomously.  Of course some of that is illegal if you don't have someone watching the thing with their unaided  eyes also.

Comment: @quiet flyer: you know you can edit it yourself, right? Anyways, I fixed it.

Comment: You have several questions that might be better asked separately. For the question about regulations, which country or regulator are you asking about?

Comment: They use jet engines for RC models like the ones sold here, for example https://www.chiefaircraft.com/radio-control/turbine-engines/jetcat.html

Comment: You should know that there's now [Drones.SE](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They create thrust the same way that the full size ones do.

- In the case of a piston engine type aircraft they have either have a miniature version of a piston engine, or an electric motor which turns the propeller.
- In the case of jet engine, like your picture, they have miniature versions of a jet engine.
- Sometimes, the jet engine in an RC aircraft is actually a propeller made to look like a jet engine.

> Also, how do they control aileron

Usually by using servos to pull cables and pullies - essentially like aircraft used to before fly-by-wire systems were introduced.

> Does an RC plane have rudder?

Some do, some don't. Its the difference between 2 and 3 axis controls. Anything like the one in your picture almost certainly do.

> Do RCs have to be registered with local aviation authorities

Sometimes, It depends on jurisdiction and and often weight.

Comment: @PerlDuck wow not cheap toys are they now!

Comment: Indeed. But impressive they are. Btw. I removed my comment and put it below the question so the OP gets notified.

Comment: I thought 2axis controls removed ailerons, not rudders, mainly because of secondary effects of rudder (induced roll)

Comment: @ManuH There are some of both.  I've flown many hours of RC with rudder-elevator and rudder-elevator-throttle, but most of my time with aileron-capable RC I've ignored the rudder,effectively flying aileron-elevator-throttle most of the time -- and there are models that simply have a fixed fin, no rudder at all (more common back when a 4-channel radio rig cost twice what a 3-channel one did).